# Force configuration in the dependency in gradle android application

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-3.0, gradle-3.0

I need to force the configuration in the gradle in my android application and my gradle verision is 3.0.1. the below is the old way of doing it and i need the equivalent of Gradle 3.0.

```
releaseCompile project(path: ':androidLibrary', configuration: 'debug')
```

My error version :

```
releaseImplementation project(path: ':androidLibrary', configuration: 'debug')
```

the above gives me an error message as

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':main@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :androidLibrary."
>
> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':main@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
>   :androidLibrary.

Comment: Check my answer about `matchingFallback` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49288390/2949966.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following instead?

```
implementation project(':androidLibrary')
```

According to Google's [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html), "targeting a specific variant of a local module dependency (for example, using configuration: 'debug') causes the following build error:"

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
  Could not resolve project :library.
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath':
  Could not resolve project :library.
```

I think you're targeting a specific variant of a local module dependency when you use the `release` prefix in `releaseImplementation` and when you include `configuration: 'debug'` in this statement:

```
releaseImplementation project(path: ':androidLibrary', configuration: 'debug')
```

It goes on to recommend the following solution:

"You should instead configure your dependencies as follows":

```
dependencies {
    // This is the old method and no longer works for local
    // library modules:
    // debugImplementation project(path: ':library', configuration: 'debug')
    // releaseImplementation project(path: ':library', configuration: 'release')

    // Instead, simply use the following to take advantage of
    // variant-aware dependency resolution. You can learn more about
    // the 'implementation' configuration in the section about
    // new dependency configurations.
    implementation project(':library')

    // You can, however, keep using variant-specific configurations when
    // targeting external dependencies. The following line adds 'app-magic'
    // as a dependency to only the "debug" version of your module.

    debugImplementation 'com.example.android:app-magic:12.3'
}
```

source: [Migrate dependency configurations for local modules](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_dependencies)

Comment: This don't address the question. He wants to force a `release` to depend on `debug` variant of `library`.
I'm actually facing the same problem, and the auto variant-resolution feature will resolve to `release` intead of `debug`.