# How to add more build types in app than library

Tags: android, gradle

Just like the example [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#build-types) I am extending my build types to add staging:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
        staging {
            initWith release
            applicationIdSuffix '.staging'
        }
    }
}
```

But I also have a dependency:

```
implementation project(':mylibrary')
```

Compilation fails because it doesn't know what to pair `staging` to in `:mylibrary`:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileStagingJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:stagingCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :mylibrary.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :mylibrary:
          - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'staging' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'staging' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'staging' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'staging' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

That's fair enough, but I cannot go through all of my libraries adding `staging` just to get a different application suffix.

I tried:

```
debugImplementation project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'debug')
releaseImplementation project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'release')
stagingImplementation project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'release')
```

But it fails:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :mylibrary.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'releaseImplementation' to configuration 'release' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :mylibrary.

debugImplementation project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'default')
releaseImplementation project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'default')
stagingImplementation project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'default')
```

This works but every build has release build of library. I don't want that, I need debug to have debug version of library.

I've seen [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081846/use-different-build-types-of-library-module-in-android-app-module-in-android-stu), but it's pre "`implementation`" and `publishNonDefault true` had no effect, same error as above.

> publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

Gradlew version 4.6

Comment: `I cannot go through all of my libraries adding staging just to get a different application suffix.` Maybe you should, OR follow another structure one lib contain all libs that belong to realease version and another contain all libs that belong to debug version, now you can go through only two libs.

Comment: @lbrahim Then those two libraries share the same issue as the app. i.e. they have `staging` but their dependencies do not.

Comment: Their dependencies depend on their status, If the main-lib is release then the the sub-libs are.

Comment: @lbrahim `release` is not the issue though is it? `staging` is the pest here. When one module is building `staging`, how can it have a dependency on a project that doesn't have `staging`?

Comment: The sub-libs of the main-lib e.g "staging" or whatever will implement the default flavor for the main-lib, which part not clear?

Comment: I recommend to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679847/android-studio-3-0-compile-issue-cannot-choose-between-configurations/45685318#45685318)

Comment: @lbrahim thanks, but seems to be all out of date. I can't go back to `debugCompile` etc. That's old stuff, replaced by `implementation` as you know.

Comment: @lbrahim the two submodule idea. I can't see that working, for the same reason as the app doesn't work. But if you can make a quick example in an answer I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Been here, done that :P

You'll need to specify `matchingFallback` with the Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 for the plugin to know which fallback build type of library to use when being compiled with app code in case a certain build type defined in your app is not found in library.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
    }
    staging {
        initWith release
        applicationIdSuffix '.staging'
        matchingFallbacks = ['release']
    }
}
```

More info here: [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#resolve_matching_errors).

Comment: If this work with *main-projects* and *sub-projects* then it would be perfect  one.

Comment: It only needs to be set in the `build.gradle` of the module that depends on the library modules that don't have the said module's build types such as `staging` in this case

Comment: Thanks so much that really did the trick. I'm just going to edit answer to the minimum I had to do. I only had to specify where it was a non-standard build type.

Comment: You may want to add a new answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081846/use-different-build-types-of-library-module-in-android-app-module-in-android-stu

Comment: +50 because you saved me a bunch of time and hair!

Comment: Thanks and happy to help :D

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a `staging` buildType in my **react native project** too, the build was fine, but for some reason **it was loading an old version of the app**.

## If your react native is loading a old version:

Try the following changes at `/android/app/build.gradle` file:

### 1. Change the buildType name from `staging` to `releaseStaging`

I don't know the reason yet. But this is the main change that made my react native app open the correct version of the app.

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    releaseStaging {
        initWith release
        ...
    }
}
```

### 2. Include the `matchingFallbacks = ['release']`, just like [@ahasbini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49288390/19110863) mentioned.

This fixed some build errors.

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    releaseStaging {
        initWith release
        matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        ...
    }
}
```

### 3. If you have hermes enabled, you should include a `releaseStagingImplementation`, just like the code below.

After including this, my app stopped to crash while starting.

```
if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    releaseStagingImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```