# Cannot find local aar built through Flutter Module

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add the flutter module as aar dependency on my Android Project. Here is the guide
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#add-the-flutter-module-as-a-dependency
I am able to generate the local AAR and I can see these steps to be done:

```
 1. Open <host>/app/build.gradle
  2. Ensure you have the repositories configured, otherwise add them:

      repositories {
        maven {
            url '/Users/asharma/Documents/Flutter/animation_module/build/host/outputs/repo'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://download.flutter.io'
        }
      }

  3. Make the host app depend on the Flutter module:

    dependencies {
      debugImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_debug:1.0
      profileImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_profile:1.0
      releaseImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_release:1.0
    }


  4. Add the `profile` build type:

    android {
      buildTypes {
        profile {
          initWith debug
        }
      }
    }
```

In my Android project, I have `app` module and `library` module. I want to include this `aar` in my `library` module, here is my `library` module `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        profile {
            initWith debug
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    debugImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_debug:1.0'
    profileImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_profile:1.0'
    releaseImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_release:1.0'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url '/Users/asharma/Documents/Flutter/animation_module/build/host/outputs/repo'
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://download.flutter.io'
    }
}
```

I have also added `mavenLocal()` at my project's `build.gradle` in repository. (Tried with and without it) But dependencies are not resolved.
I get an error:

```
Could not find com.example.animation_module:flutter_debug:1.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/example/animation_module/flutter_debug/1.0/flutter_debug-1.0.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/example/animation_module/flutter_debug/1.0/flutter_debug-1.0.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/example/animation_module/flutter_debug/1.0/flutter_debug-1.0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/example/animation_module/flutter_debug/1.0/flutter_debug-1.0.jar
Required by:
    project :app > project :animation_flutter_sdk
```

I know dependency is not present on the remote at `https://dl.google.com` but it is present in my local and gradle should pick it up from my local. Please help me how to build this project.

Comment: Same hier. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I haven't found a solution. I opened a ticket https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57020#issuecomment-627911003

Comment: I solved my issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have a project with several library modules and an app module. I faced the same issue as I wanted to start the flutter module from one of my library modules.

I solved it by adding

```
repositories {
maven {
    url '../path/to_your/flutter_repo'
}
maven {
    url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io'
}
```

in both app module and library module `build.gradle`

I didn't need `mavenLocal()`.

I also needed to add

```
profile {
    initWith debug
}
```

in each modules `build.gradle`.

This is now how my app module and library module `build.gradle` looks like:

App module `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url '../core/webshop/flutter_repo'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion toolVersions.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
       ...
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
        profile {
            initWith debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Project modules
    implementation project('your_lib_module1')
    implementation project('your_lib_module2')
    ...

}
```

Library module `build.gradle`, where you want to add flutter module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    maven {
        url './flutter_repo'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion toolVersions.compileSdk

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }

        profile {
            initWith debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Project modules
    implementation project('your_lib_module3')

    // flutter
    debugImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_debug:1.0'
    profileImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_profile:1.0'
    releaseImplementation 'com.example.animation_module:flutter_release:1.0'
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the repositories into the settings.gradle like this  ->

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    
    maven {
        url '/Users/asharma/Documents/Flutter/animation_module/build/host/outputs/repo'
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://download.flutter.io'
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and solve it adding in repositories of `settings.gradle` inside of dependencyResolutionManagement

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url '/yourpath/your_flutter_module/build/host/outputs/repo'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem, it is solved by setting the configurations

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ....
        }
        profile {
            ....
        }
        debug {
            ....
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    // Initializes a placeholder for the profileImplementation dependency configuration
    profileImplementation {}
}

dependencies {
        debugImplementation xxx
        // Then it can work
        profileImplementation xxx
        releaseImplementation xxx

}
```

[Picking a specific build type in a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771532/picking-a-specific-build-type-in-a-dependency/64696476#64696476)

Comment: Don't copy-paste and link your own answers. If you think that this question can benefit from the exact same answer as another question - this might suggest that tis question is a duplicate and should be flagged